# YouTube issue with Lubuntu 16.04

Tags: flash, performance, overheating, youtube, compaq

I guess I'm a newbie when it comes to linux, but I managed to perform a clean install on an old Compaq mini netbook (CQ10-120LA). Everything is smooth except when it comes to playing YouTube videos, which is the main reason I wanted to get this laptop to work again. This happened recently after it updated to 16.04, I don't remember the previous version but it wasn't so much of an issue. It also overheats a lot (I cleaned the interior and replaced the thermal compound already).

I tried Minitube (didn't work), so I'm looking for a reasonable solution that doesn't take a whole lot of knowledge in order to make this thing a simple and functional box, feel free to recommend another distro. Any help is appreciated. Chrome and firefox are the only browsers I've tried.

Relevant specs of the netbook:

- Intel Atom N270, 1.6 Ghz Single core (32 bit architecture)
- 2Gb of ram
- 180 Gb HDD

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/885219/edit) and add which browser you're using.

Comment: And if you can't get it to work in the browser, you can try this: http://www.webupd8.org/2015/02/youtube-viewer-complete-youtube-client.html. VLC can also play youtube videos, just paste the URL into the "open network stream" box.

Comment: An Intel Atom N270 will **not**  play HD video, Youtube or local file. Set your expectations accordingly.

Comment: I never expected this little thing to play 1080p or even 720p video, I'm well aware this system is pretty much potato.

Answer (score 3):

A single-core [Intel Atom N270](http://ark.intel.com/products/36331/Intel-Atom-Processor-N270-512K-Cache-1_60-GHz-533-MHz-FSB), paired with the *Intel Graphics Media Accelerator 950* provided by [Intel 82945GSE Graphics and Memory Controller](http://ark.intel.com/products/36549/Intel-82945GSE-Graphics-and-Memory-Controller), supports at most **480P** videos for online video streaming or reproducing local files.

Due to limited hardware it may work better if using a dedicated client. Two alternatives suggested in comments:

1. VLC

   ```
   sudo apt install vlc
   ```

   *File* -> *Open Network Stream...*
2. YouTube-Viewer

   ```
   sudo apt-add-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
   sudo apt update
   sudo apt install youtube-viewer
   ```